# How to add "Authentication-Results:" - Debian Squeeze+postfix+opendkim+SPF checks

Tags: debian, authentication, debian-squeeze

I have installed Debian Squeeze on my VPS, I use it as mail server only, packages installed are: Postfix+openDKIM+SPF_checks_with_Postfix.

All works fine, SPF & DKIM passes authentication, but the problem is that in the email message headers "Authentication-Results:" field is missing. So, Postfix doesn't add this header to the message.

As I understand this is "RFC 5451 Authentication Results Header"

I have added in opendkim.conf:
AlwaysAddARHeader   yes

but the result is the same. Still no, "Authentication-Results:" field in email header.

How can I add/install it to the server?

Sorry, I am beginner in Debian, please help

Answer (score 1):

Do you know that Debian Squeeze is no longer `stable`? Please considier upgrading your Debian to `wheezy`.

You are using very old Debian distribution. OpenDKIM is kinda old there (2.0.1 vs 2.6.8 in wheezy), there is known [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=652932). Please upgrade opendkim to newer version and your problem should be fixed.

Comment: By upgrading to Wheeze I have problems with Dovecot configuration and I have not found appropriate script/tutorial to install/configure server, therefore downgraded to Debian 6.0